# Problems with system standby in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04

I can't put my Ubuntu (9.04) in Standby mode. When I try to do so, it appears to do something and then turns the screen off. However, the fans remain on and by measuring the amount of electricity it uses it doesn't seem to be actually asleep. At that point, I can't really wake it up either - pressing keyboard keys, clicking the mouse buttons, pressing the power button - none of those help. The only thing that works is pressing the reset button which reboots the pc. There's nothing in /var/log/messages either.

Any ideas/suggestions? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

- There was nothing in dmesg.0 at that time
- I also tried [s2ram](http://en.opensuse.org/S2ram) but it didn't recognize my machine and --force had the same effect as the regular suspend from the ubuntu menus

EDIT: 
Btw, my motherboard is PCCHIPS A11G 6.00 PG

EDIT: 
I tried an opensuse livecd and windows 7 and both had the same problem with suspend - it is starting to look like a motherboard problem

Comment: I had the same issue on my hardware and I never found a fix. The same hardware doesn't have the issue with fedora 11.

Answer (score 1):

/bin/tail /var/log/dmesg.0 after this happens and return with result.